# Entering a letter then minus to the alphabet

Tags: c

i am making a program that discard a letter from a list if you enter a letter, can anyone help me. thanks.

in example:
(BEFORE)

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
enter a letter: A

(AFTER ENTERING A LETTER 'A')

_BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
enter a letter:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    int alphabet[26];
    char letter;
    int i;
    int j;

    alphabet[0] = 'A';
    for(i = 0;i < 26; i++)
    {
        alphabet[i] = alphabet[0];
        printf ("%c", alphabet[i], alphabet[i]);
        alphabet[0]++;
    }

        printf("\n\nenter the letter you want to remove in the alphabet: ");
        scanf("%c", letter);

        while(j<alphabet[i])
        {
            if(letter==alphabet[i])
            {
                j--;
            }
        }
}
```

The problem is its not removing the letter in the alphabet when i entered the letter i want to remove. please help. thanks.

EDIT: one last thing, how can i make it only one input?, i mean if i input the same letter in 2nd time it will said "you already input that letter".

Comment: What is the question? What is not working in your program?

Comment: @Étienne sorry i forgot the question, the question is its not removing the letter in the alphabet when i enter the letter i want to remove.

Comment: instead of writing Characters to your array you could just write in the integer number of the char and if you print it out you translate it to a character (in this minimum example it will not bring much performance, but it may be helpful in other tasks ;) ) because the computer is fine with the int ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that the letters are contiguos, as in ASCII, but you cannot assume that in **C**.

The next line has a duplicated argument:

```
   printf ("%c", alphabet[i], alphabet[i]);
```

Drop the last `alphabet[i]`.

Your last `if()` sentence is wrong: the comparisson must be done with `==`.

It is not clear at all what do you want to do.

EDIT:

I would do the program in this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char alphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    char letter;

    printf("Choose a letter: ");
    letter = getchar();

    printf("\n\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
      if (letter == alphabet[i]) 
         {
            alphabet[i] = '_';
            break;   /* This terminates the for() loop */
         }        

     printf("Result: %s \n", alphabet);
}
```

EDIT2: I have changed the declaration of `alphabet`, because the string constant has to be modified later...

Comment: Sir, i want to do is when i enter a letter, it will remove the entered letter in the alphabet. sorry im not that pro in programming.

Comment: Ok, but your last comparisson is wrong, because it is always `true`. You are doing an assignment, not a comparisson there. Change `=` to `==`.

Comment: i already change it. so how can i remove a letter in the alphabet after i enter the letter i want to remove?

Comment: I've added some code. After choosing a letter with `getchar()`, a for() loop iterates searching for the letter in your string alphabet. If it encounters it, it is replaced by an underscore.

Comment: @pablo1977 how can i make it case insensitive?

Comment: @user2803376 by converting lower-case characters into upper-case characters before doing any tests. `man 3 toupper`

Comment: one last thing, how can i make it only one input, imean if i input the same letter in 2nd time it will said "you already input that letter".

Comment: @pablo1977 one last thing, how can i make it only one input?, imean if i input the same letter in 2nd time it will said "you already input that letter".

Answer (score 1):

you are *assigning* a value to `letter` with the the statement

```
letter=alphabet[i]
```

this statement will always be true, unless `alphabet[i]` is `0`.

use comparision instead

```
letter==alphabet[i]
```

also your `while` loop is a bit weird, as the value of `j` will be undefined in the beginning , so your comparision will be undefined.

```
   while(j<alphabet[i])
    {
        if(letter=alphabet[i])
        {
            j--;
        }
```

probably you simply want to do something like:

```
   for(i = 0;i < 26; i++) {
      if(alphabeth[i]==letter) {
          alphabeth[i]='_';
      }
   }
```

if you only want to replace the first occurence of the letter, insert a `break;` after `alphabeth[i]='_';`

and you probably don't want to have magic values like "26" occuring multiple times in your sourcecode.

instead use something like

```
 #define ALPHABETSIZE 26
```

and replace all occurences of `26` by `ALPHABETSIZE`

Comment: i already change it, but its not removing the letter i entered from the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you want to go through your array and check if the entered char matches any in the array.

Is there any reason, why you dont use a for-loop like this and set the array position to 0 instead of the while statement?

```
for(i=0;i<26;i++)
{
   if(letter == alphabet[i]) 
      alphabet[i] = "_"; // or setting it to 0 if you use and int-array
}
```

Or do I get something wrong here?

Comment: doing `alphabet[i]=0` will break the printout..e.g. if the user entered `C`, the next printout will only print *AB*

Comment: @umläute ... yes of course, it did not point out, that i connected that one to my statement in the comment that he could use integers instead of chars... i edit this in my post, thanks

Comment: yup :) when it matches the letter from the alphabet, it will be replace by _ and cannot be entered again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here that you are doing to make it hard for yourself.

You need to use "==" not "=" to compare two variables

Your value for "j" is not initialised so "j--" would be undefined

Its probably better to keep all your types the same and make the array a "char" array not an "int" array.

To remove an element from your array "int alphabet[26];" would be very difficult, it would probably be easier to make this a "string" exercise. All you can really do is to make a "blank" letter by

```
alphabet[j] = ' ';
```

I think its possible to make a better design though if you explain your requirements more clearly :)

Comment: if make it like this: `char alphabet[27]={'a' - 'z'}` then how can i remove the letter i entered in the alphabet?

Comment: You cannot remove it, it's a fixed size array, you cannot change it's size, you can only put some different character instead of the letter you want to remove. so e.g. when having {'a','b','c'} you can't remove 'b' so you have {'a','c'} (you must use lists not arrays for this), but you can put ' ' instead of 'b' and get {'a',' ','c'} and treat spaces as removed elements.

Comment: exactly (+1)... probably what you want to do is make a "string" with "abc....xyz" in it and then use that to make a new string (lets say remove 'a') "bc...xyz". This would be very different to your solution, but not that hard. You'll need to allocate and deallocate memory to do such things... (look up things like strcpy and strcat)